# Selecting WebElements in JUnit @Test by calling method that defines WebElement paths

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm creating a Junit test in Selenium that calls a method that defines WebElements that need to be selected during automation.

When the Junit test is run it only launches the browser, goes to the webpage, and does not select the WebElements. This does work when run in Selenium as a regular Java application.

```
@Test
public void downTimeTestCase() {
    System.out.println("Running test 'Down Time'");
    defineWebElements();

    downTime.click();
    dateSelector.click();
}

public void defineWebElements() {
    downTime = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*.   [@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));
    uph = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));

}
```

I expect the test to select the webpage WebElements via their xpath but instead the webpage is launched and nothing happens. No WebElements are selected.

Comment: dateSelector is not defined, uph is not used.

Comment: Please update your code with an actual running example, a [mcve]. What you have won't build, let alone run.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see your point, but this should work:

```
@Test
public void downTimeTestCase() {
    System.out.println("Running test 'Down Time'");
    defineWebElements().get(0).click();
    defineWebElements().get(1).click();

}

public List<WebElement> defineWebElements() {
    WebElement downTime = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*.   [@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));
    WebElement uph = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));
    List<WebElement> elements = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
    elements.add(downTime);
    elements.add(uph);
    return elements;
}
```

or

```
@Test
public void downTimeTestCase() {
    System.out.println("Running test 'Down Time'");
    defineWebElements();
}

public void defineAndClickWebElements() {
    WebElement downTime = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*.   [@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));
    WebElement uph = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));
    downTime.click();
    uph.click();
}
```

Comment: The first case you are using `.get()` to click on elements... which one is which? It's not clear from your implementation. The second, the method is called `defineWebElements()` but you have added clicks which is not the way OP wanted it and makes the name confusing since it isn't doing what it claims to do.

Comment: .get(0) returns first one, .get(1) second and so on. You are right about the method name, I've renamed it.

Comment: Yes, `.get(0)` gets the first one but my point is which one is the first one? It's not obvious from 0/1. Is it `downTime` or `uph`? You'd have to look in the code to see which means it's not a good design.